# Is there any Equivalent to ValidateAntiForgeryToken in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm looking at SS code in github and I can't to find any equivalent to ValidateAntiForgeryToken because I don't want to reinvent the wheel and I'd like to reuse as much as possible the SS framework, I think that a solution could be to create a custom RequestFilterAttribute, any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up by creating a requestFilterAttibute with similar capabilities of the asp.net mvc

this is the code I've done so far:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class ValidateHttpAntiForgeryToken : RequestFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
        {
           try
            {
                if (IsAjaxRequest(req))
                    ValidateRequestHeader(req);
                else
                    AntiForgery.Validate();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                res.StatusCode = 403;
                res.StatusDescription = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        private void ValidateRequestHeader(IHttpRequest req)
        {
            var cookie = req.Cookies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value.Name.Contains(AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName));
            if (cookie.Value == null)
            {
                throw new HttpAntiForgeryException(String.Format("Missing {0} cookie", AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName));
            }
            IEnumerable<string> xXsrfHeaders = req.Headers.GetValues("__RequestVerificationToken");
            if (xXsrfHeaders == null || !xXsrfHeaders.Any())
                throw new HttpAntiForgeryException("Missing X-XSRF-Token HTTP header");
            AntiForgery.Validate(cookie.Value.Value, xXsrfHeaders.FirstOrDefault());

        }

        private static bool IsAjaxRequest(IHttpRequest request)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> xRequestedWithHeaders = request.Headers.GetValues("X-Requested-With");
            if (xRequestedWithHeaders != null && xRequestedWithHeaders.Any())
            {
                string headerValue = xRequestedWithHeaders.FirstOrDefault();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(headerValue))
                {
                    return String.Equals(headerValue, "XMLHttpRequest", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that wheel has already been invented:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack/Html/AntiXsrf

Comment: thanks @Jon Canning I saw that code earlier but I can't see the full picture of how am I going to implement a Xsrf validation against a service Method?

Comment: I know that I can use the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() helper to generate the token, now I'm searching for a filer or a filerattribute that validates the request something like http://kamranicus.com/Blog/Posts/70/protip-using-anti-forgery-token-with-aspnet-web-ap

Comment: actually that is what I was asking for: "I think that a solution could be to create a custom RequestFilterAttribute, any other ideas?" I just was asking for other options

Comment: Sorry, I deleted that comment when I realised that