# Call MVC method from Silverlight with "__RequestVerificationToken" parameter

Tags: silverlight, security, model-view-controller

I have a Silverlight control in my MVC site, the silverlight is a Upload File, this calls to Method in the controller, but I need add the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` tag on the method.

I send the `"__RequestVerificationToken"` parameter on the query string, but this don´t works.

any idea?

(Sorry for my english)

My js code:

```
function getToken() {
        return $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
    }
```

My Silverlight code

```
string token = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("getToken").ToString();
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenWriteAsync(new Uri(string.Format("{0}?__RequestVerificationToken={1}&fileName={2}&size={3}", url, token, fileName, fileSize), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: can you post the code to check how you're "sending" the token?

Comment: @Pedro this is my code

Comment: you are trying to validate yourself the token I would recomend you to do a custom attribute to perform that task

Comment: That is an option, but the site will lose security, no? As I read, MVC control the cookies too, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: if you do your own implementation ValidateAntiForgeryToken you run your security, I've done one for ServiceStack that have a simmilar functionality as the mvc implementation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089214/is-there-any-equivalent-to-validateantiforgerytoken-in-servicestack

Comment: Great, I'm going to implement something similar. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help prevent CSRF attacks, ASP.NET MVC uses anti-forgery tokens, also called request verification tokens which is the attribute you're trying to implement the ValidateAntiForgeryToken practically should provide the RequestVerificationToken:

1. In the request using a hidden element in a form
2. a HTTP only
   cookie named __RequestVerificationTokenwith the token on it

   The tokens are generated randomly on each request

in the case using silverlight you have to make sure you are sending the token through the request that way the validate method will compare the token from both sources, you probably could do that by creating a web requets.

**Edit:**
in the case you are validating the token you don't need to include the default attribute that comes OOB for mvc you can create your own and validate the token there

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think than the code is correct (without the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] tag this works)